# Custom Element and Leaflet and Markers not aligning

Tags: javascript, leaflet, custom-element

I am dabbling and learning to create my first Web Component / Custom Elements to display Leaflet Maps.
Whilst I can display the map I can't for the life of me to get it to centre of the div.

The Console view of the div is

```
<div id="mapdiv" class="leaflet-container leaflet-retina leaflet-fade-anim leaflet-grab leaflet-touch-drag" tabindex="0" style="height: 400px; width: 600px; position: relative; outline: none;">
```

My Javascript code is as below

```
      let shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
      var mapdiv = document.createElement("div");
      mapdiv.setAttribute("id", "mapdiv");
      mapdiv.style.height = "400px";
      mapdiv.style.width = "600px";
      mapdiv.innerHTML =
        '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA=="crossorigin=""/>';
      shadow.appendChild(mapdiv);

      var map = L.map(mapdiv).setView([-33.75969, 151.09488], 8);

      L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
        attribution:
          '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      }).addTo(map);
      L.marker([-33.75969, 151.09488])
        .addTo(map)
        .bindPopup("This is not working")
        .openPopup();
    }
  }
);
```

})();

Cheers

Comment: If your element is not yet in the actual page DOM, Leaflet may still have trouble determining its size. Try invalidating its size once it is displayed.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you mean by "try invalidating its size". Thanks Heaps

Comment: He means that you should try this, after adding the marker to the map: `setTimeout(function(){ map.invalidateSize()}, 400);` or in the onReadyEvent from the document.

Comment: And if that above not working, try to add the CSS while page loading or/and append it to the `head` and not to the `mapdiv`

Comment: Thanks mate. I will give this a bash.